# What approach can be take to design a food menu intelligently?

Tags: dataset, predictive-modeling, training

I am given following problem, for which I am seeking for advice.

Problem Statement

Suppose you are given a catalogue of dishes with their cost and calories. Can you design an algorithm/model which can generate a menu of item such that items in menu has cost less than certain( say X) dollar and calories
(say Y) approx equal to certain value.

```
X = 800
Y = 20

menu_items = method(calories=Y, cost=X)   # Generate a menu under 20$ and approx 800 calories.
```

Dataset can look like

```
Item               Type             Cost             Calories
A                  Bread            1.5              300
B                  Gravy            6                500
C                  Bread            1                100
D                  Salad            5                100
E                  Dessert          3                400
```

**What I am looking for**
I am looking for advice that

- what kind of models I can look into to solve this problem, since it is neither classification nor regression nor clusterring.
- If their is any related research paper that you know, i will be more than happy to read that out.

**Note**: I tried to ask chatGpt the same question
**Question**: Can you generate a menu under 5$ with 800 calories?
ChatGPT gave me the menu but since i want to have similar behaviour on my own data-set so I need to comeup with custom model.

Comment: You can fine-tune GPT-3 on your data and use it similarly to ChatGPT

Comment: Yes, I know i can fine-tune chatGPT. But that model expects 
`Intent - Completion` pair, in my case Intent is just couple of variation of one question whereas completion is the combination of items satisfying the constraint. So, not sure how can I pass data-set for this usecase to chatGPT.

Comment: As far as I know, OpenAI has not released any way to fine-tune ChatGPT yet, have they? I referred to GPT-3, which is just a language model.

Comment: This can be formulated as an optimization problem, for which you can use a python library such as [`PuLP`](https://coin-or.github.io/pulp/main/index.html). For the example you posted you could even make use of the 'Solver' add-in for excel, which gave me the solution of selecting two of type E (without knowing if you have any constraints on the maximum number of each item that can be selected).